# Simple Jquery Question

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

HI there ... im am trying to create a simple Jquery within Droppable. The page works and allows me to drop a video onto the selected droppable area (div class="roundedVideoDrop"), but I want to stop the user from being able to drop more than 1 video in each div, which has been created.

My code for this is :

```
$("div.roundedVideoDrop").droppable({
            activeClass: 'highlight',
            hoverClass: 'highlight-accept',
            drop: function(event, ui){
                if $(this).sibling('video').count() == 0 {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
```

What im attempting to do is to check and see if there is another sibling (i.e another  within the ) if there is then the video being dragged cannot be dropped into the , otherwise it is allowed.

This will not work, in fact is kicking up a parse error within Safari and I have been trying all morning to get it working but no luck. Could anyone tell me the correct way of doing it?

Thanks so much

Comment: Thank for the quick responses! I want to be able to stop the user from being able to drop the video tag into the div tag when a video tag has already been dropped into the selected div. The example below are not allowing me to do this, im still looking for a solution at present but no luck as yet!

Answer (score 0):

Try `$(this).sibling('video').size()` instead of `$(this).sibling('video').count()`

Comment: `$(this).sibling('video').length` to avoid one function call overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use children not siblings if you are looking inside the current drop zone

```
$("div.roundedVideoDrop").droppable({
            activeClass: 'highlight',
            hoverClass: 'highlight-accept',
            drop: function(event, ui){
                return  !$(this).children('video').length;
            }
```